# Empty data after OptionalHeader

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

I'm working on PE parser, just for learning purposes. 
As the doc said, the first section header should be immediately after OptionalHeader, but in my case I have a lot of empty data before first header.
Here is my code to calculate where should be firtst section:

```
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* inth = get_nt_headers(buffer);

DWORD optional_headers_size = inth->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader;
DWORD calculated_ptr = (DWORD)inth + optional_headers_size;

printf("Pointer to IMAGE_NT_HEADERS: %p\n", inth);

printf("Size of optional headers: %x\n", optional_headers_size);

printf("Pointer to first section header: %p\n", calculated_ptr);

BYTE* pointer = (BYTE*)calculated_ptr;
```

When I iterate over the 'pointer' I see a lot of nullable data, so it is not section I need. PEView or Hexplorer shows empty data too. Why is that?
This 'nullable' part of data takes about 24 bytes.

App which I analze is a simple HelloWorld.exe.

I'm confused with one more thing.

In FileHeader I has set 13 number of sections, but if I take a look on PEView in IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER I see 16 sections but the last 3 sections have any assigned values, which means that the RVA and Size are set to 0. 
This sections are: DELAY_IMPORT_DESCRIPTORS, CLI_HEADER, but the last doesn't has any name.

I calculated that these three last section's size is 24 bytes.
This the excatly the same as I mentioned before.

So how I can calculate where excatly is the firts IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER?

Problem solved, but I'm not sure about my solution.

```
DWORD padding = (IMAGE_NUMBEROF_DIRECTORY_ENTRIES - inth->FileHeader.NumberOfSections) * sizeof(IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY);
DWORD calculated_ptr = (DWORD)inth + padding + optional_headers_size;
```

Comment: Why are you not sure about your solution, exactly?

Comment: your "solution" of course wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all - never use `DWORD` in place pointer. this is error. `DWORD` is always 4 byte size, when pointer 4 or 8. code like

`DWORD calculated_ptr = (DWORD)inth + optional_headers_size;`

always wrong. you can use `DWORD_PTR`(which is exactly pointer size) instead `DWORD`.

then `SizeOfOptionalHeader` how easy understand is size of `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` which is **part** of `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS`. but code like this

`DWORD_PTR calculated_ptr = (DWORD_PTR)inth + inth->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader;` use `SizeOfOptionalHeader` as size of `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS`. you simply confuse size of `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` with size of `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`

so correct solution will be

```
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pish = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)(
        (ULONG_PTR)&inth->OptionalHeader + inth->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader);
```

need add `SizeOfOptionalHeader` not to `inth` (address of `PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS`) but to `&inth->OptionalHeader`

or better use `PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pish = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(inth);`

the `IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION` - this is ready macro defined in `winnt.h` which have the same effect (produce same code) as `(PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((ULONG_PTR)&inth->OptionalHeader + inth->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader);`

Comment: Your's soluution is better than main. But I have one more question. Why pointer to OptionalHeader need to be casted to ULONG_PTR?

Comment: @bielu000 - it not need to be casted. but we need do some pointer arithmetic. we need add some offset ( `SizeOfOptionalHeader`) to this pointer. how do this ? for example by temporary cast to `ULONG_PTR` or to `BYTE*`.

Comment: Ok thanks. One more simple question :) In my case is better to cast to ULONG_PTR, BYTE * or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @bielu000 - if you know *c* - you must know that this is absolute nothing change